# using mongoose middleware with SchemaFactory

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema, mongoose-middleware

I am trying to use a mongoose middleware to recursively delete references to this object in another objects array (delete `task` references in `taskList` with the id from `task`)

The problematic function:

```js
TaskSchema.pre('deleteOne', function(next) {
    console.log(this)
    const task: any = this
    this.model('Set').deleteMany({ $pullAll: { taskList: Types.ObjectId(task.id.toString()) } }, next)
})
```

This throws an ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object when called by

```js
const task = await this.taskSchema.deleteOne({ _id: id })
```

Further an issue is that in the last line `this.model` => I don't use model anywhere since instead of declaring a model i use:

```js
export type TaskDocument = Task & Document
export const TaskSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Task)
```

Task Object:

[image]

Set Object:

[image]

Comment: arrow function has lexical scope. Change that callback passed to `.pre` to a function instead.

Comment: this now throws me an ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object

Comment: it seems like there is no way to use schema.model() with nestjs/mongoose since u don't build any models at all.